# Como marcar um input radio ao clicar em uma DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

A pergunta é auto explicativa.

Tenho um `form` com 3 `divs`, cada div possui uma `img` e um `radio`, gostaria que ao clicar nas imgs, o `radio` que esta na mesma `div` da `img` clicada seja marcado.

Ps: Acredito que seja simples de se resolver com *JS.* Se puderem me indicar um norte de por onde começar a estudar *JS*(do zero), eu agradeço.

Comment: Comece colocando o que vc já tem de código html/css que já ajuda...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Englobe sua imagem com um `label` e atribua ele ao mesmo `id` do `radio` que já resolve seu problema:

```
<input name="teste" type="radio" id="test1" />
<label for="test1">
    <img src="path-da-imagem" />
</label>
```

Comment: Perfeito. Pode me indicar material de estudo JS para quem já trabalha com HTML e CSS, mas nao saca nada de js?

Comment: @Amauri https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Então @Amauri, meu material de estudo é o Google mesmo kkk, não sou muito bom de javascript tbm mas o link do Valdeir vai te ajudar.